# 0000-00-00 00:00:00 date in table when is set to be NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

Why?

In the scheme I have:

```
`date_published` DATETIME NOT NULL,
```

but now when I:

```
mysql> select min(date_published) from articles;
+---------------------+
| min(date_published) |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (5.47 sec)
```

But when I:

```
mysql> select * from articles where date_published = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
ERROR 1525 (HY000): Incorrect DATETIME value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

I don't understand. How did I insert that?

How do I find the rows that have this date?

*Update*

```
>>> db.execute("INSERT INTO articles (edition_id, url, date_published, title, weight) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (1, "", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "", 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ... yadda yadda stack trace
packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 784, in _handle_result
    raise get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'date_published' at row 1
```

I've tried it from both mysql client and from the code. Both don't seem to work when I test it yet the row is in the table.

*Update 2*

After disabling the `NO_ZERO_DATE` in my client for the session I was able to find the rows that cause this problem.

They were inserted with the date `'0003-01-26 00:00:00+00:00'`

And now when I query for that I find them, but the value is 0000 instead if 0003:

```
mysql> select date_published from articles where date_published = '0003-01-26 00:00:00+00:00';
+---------------------+
| date_published      |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
4 rows in set (5.41 sec)
```

The `+00:00` is important, without that I get an empty set.

Comment: Note that MySQL date times *never* have an offset.  If you specify one, it will cause a warning or an error.

Comment: It doesn't error or warn me though. And it obviously does store this data as it doesn't return anything when I don't include +00:00.

Comment: That just means your +00:00 I'd making it entirely misparse your date

Comment: Should I file a bug with mysql?

Comment: ah, it appears mysql started allowing an offset to be specified with 8.0.19, but that it doesn't work correctly with dates before 1901.  yes, you should file a bug.  and you should avoid specifying offset; it doesn't not get stored, just adjusts the date that is stored.  you can find your records with just `date_published=timestamp(0)`

Comment: @ysth tested in MySQL 8, `timestamp(0)` returns NULL. However, `year(dt) + month(dt) + day(dt) + hour(dt) + minute(dt) + second(dt) = 0` works.

Comment: Timestamp(0) is just convenient shorthand for '0000-00-00 00:00:00', which indeed will not work with no_zero_date, but I thought you'd turned that off.  Nice workaround you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably inserted the zero date at some time in the past when the MySQL Server configuration allowed it.

Zero dates used to be allowed by default, and as of MySQL 5.7, they are not allowed by default. This is considered an improvement, because 0000-00-00 is not a valid date. I.e. it doesn't appear in any calendar.

The configuration that determines whether these dates are allowed is the [SQL mode NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date). When this mode is enabled, an SQL expression that casts '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as a datetime value returns an error.

If that data is already stored in your table, you can at least fetch it. But you can't form a new value like that, including the literal value you used in your WHERE clause.

To search for that value, you have to change your `sql_mode` configuration option, at least temporarily in the session where you run that query. I would recommend do not change it globally. It's a good thing to disallow invalid dates.

The manual says:

> Because NO_ZERO_DATE is deprecated; expect it to be removed in a future release of MySQL as a separate mode name and its effect included in the effects of strict SQL mode.

So in some future version of MySQL, you might have to disable strict mode to access such date values. I recommend you replace those values now with either some valid datetime value, or else NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ☺️ I started this docker container today, and it's version 8. I will try disable it in my client and find the row. And see how I got that in. 

You agree this shouldn't be possible right?

Comment: If you use the default SQL mode, it shouldn't be possible. But any session can change the SQL mode. At my last job, the developers coded their Rails framework so that it disabled strict mode as the first thing after connecting to the database. So all clients were running in non-strict mode. I could only shake my head.

Comment: Yeah we use a bog standard python mysql connector connection. No changes at all.

Comment: I would enable the MySQL general query log, and then test out your python script. That will show if it's changing the sql mode after it connects.

Comment: Yes! I just did! I'll update my question! 

Comment: I'm wondering if your app is trying to insert dates in MM-DD-YY format. Keep in mind MySQL only allows dates in YYYY-MM-DD format. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html

Comment: Please see my update in the question ☺️

Comment: Okay, something weird is going on. But if you read the manual I linked to, 0003-01-26 is not in the valid range for datetime anyway. You need to use YYYY-MM-DD format.